# Trying to display div on radio button click

Tags: javascript, php

I was hoping to get some help with hiding/showing a div when a radio button is clicked.

the JS i have is

```
function showOptions(id)
{
  document.getElementById(id).style.display="block"; 
}
```

I have a php script that creates a form with 7-10 yes/no questions.  When I select "no" I want the div to show with the additional options (checkboxes)

```
<li>Lorem Ispum?    <br>    
  <input type="radio" name="3" value="yes" onchange="hideOptions(100003)">Yes          
  <input type="radio" name="3" value="no" onchange="showOptions(100003)">No
  <div id="100003" style="border-color: blue; border-style: solid; margin: 2px; display:none">
    <input type="checkbox" name="10004">Bacon ipsum dolor amet filet mignon turkey pork chop rump swine, shank tail beef ribs capicola salami ball tip drumstick pastrami ribeye. Andouille tail bacon ball tip brisket
  </div>
</li>
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to be working and I cannot figure out what is causing the problem.

here is the PHP part that builds this:

```
if($row['question_form_type']=='boolean') {
  echo "<br><input type = 'radio' name = ".$row['question_id']." value = 'yes' onChange = 'hideOptions($option_id)'>Yes ";
  $option_id =$row['question_id']+100000;
  echo "<input type = 'radio'  name  = ".$row['question_id']." value = 'no' onChange = 'showOptions($option_id)'>No
        <div id = $option_id style = 'border-color: blue; border-style: solid; margin: 2px; display:dnone'>";
  $optionSQL = "select option_id, option_suggestion from sandbox_feedback_options where question_id = ".$row['question_id']." and option_type like  '%".$type_array[$x]."%'";
  $oresult = $conn->query($optionSQL);
  if ($oresult->num_rows > 0) {
    while($orow = $oresult->fetch_assoc()) {
      $od = $orow['option_id']+10000;
      echo "<input type = 'checkbox' name = $od>".$orow['option_suggestion']."</input><p>";
  }
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

-IJC

Here is the full PHP Script:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function showDiv(id)

      {

                html = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
      document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = html;
                 }

    function showOptions(o_id) {
        document.getElementById(o_id).style.display = "block";
   alert (o_id);
         }

</script>

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
<form action = 'email_feedback.php'>
<?php
include ("../config/dbConnector.php");
include ("../config/curlWrap.php");
echo '<label>Ticket Id</label>
<input type = "text" name = "ticket_id">
<label>Reviewer</label>
<input type = "text" name = "reviewer">';
$getQSQL = "select distinct question_type from sandbox_feedback where     question_type not like '%All%'";
$type_array = array();
echo "<select onChange = 'showDiv(value)' required>
  <option>Select Question Type</option>";
  $result = $conn->query($getQSQL);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<option>".$row['question_type']."</option>";
      $type_array[] = $row['question_type'];
      }}

echo "</select>";
for($x = 0;$x<sizeof($type_array);$x++)
{
echo "<div id = '".$type_array[$x]."' style = 'display:none'><ol>";
$questionSQL = "select question_id, question, question_form_type from sandbox_feedback where question_type in ('".$type_array[$x]."', 'All')";
 $result = $conn->query($questionSQL);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "<li>".$row['question'];

 if($row['question_form_type']=='boolean')
   {
      echo "<br><input type = 'radio' name = ".$row['question_id']." value = 'yes' >Yes ";

      $option_id = $type_array[$x]."_";
      $option_id .=$row['question_id']+100000;

      echo "<input type = 'radio'  name  = ".$row['question_id']." value = 'no' onClick = 'showOptions($option_id)'>No
       <div id =$option_id style = 'border-color: blue; border-style: solid; margin: 2px; display:none'>";
      $optionSQL = "select option_id, option_suggestion from sandbox_feedback_options where question_id = ".$row['question_id']." and option_type like  '%".$type_array[$x]."%'";
      $oresult = $conn->query($optionSQL);
         if ($oresult->num_rows > 0) {
      while($orow = $oresult->fetch_assoc()) {
             $od = $orow['option_id']+10000;
          echo "<input type = 'checkbox' name =     $od>".$orow['option_suggestion']."</input><p>";

}
echo "</div>";}


    }
 echo "</li>";
 }}
echo "</ol></div>";
}


 echo "<div id = 'question'></div>";

 ?>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
```

I'm thinking because I have hidden divs that have the same IDs maybe causing the issue.

Comment: `getElementById` retrieves objects from the DOM given an `id`, not a `name`

Comment: Hey Nathan,  Thanks for looking at it for me. I have  `<div id = $option_id` in the PHP so i'm not checking against name.

Comment: Your PHP says "onClick" but your HTML says "onchange." If onchange is what's really happening, then you have competing events, where one shows and the other hides.

Comment: sorry, i switched it to onClick to see if that would fix it but originally was using onchange.  I was going to add a hideOptions function to hide the div after I got it working to show.

Comment: Can you show us the DOCTYPE line at the top of the HTML please? If you're still using HTML4, the problem could have to do with using an integer as the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is the scope of functions, put the two function (show/hide) on HEAD without wrap code for "onload" of the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showOptions(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        }
        function hideOptions(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <li>
        Lorem Ispum?    <br>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="yes" onchange="hideOptions('100003');">Yes
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="no" onchange="showOptions('100003');">No

        <div id="100003" style="border-color: blue; border-style: solid; margin: 2px; display:none">
            <input type="checkbox" name="10004">Bacon ipsum dolor amet filet mignon turkey pork chop rump swine, shank tail beef ribs capicola salami ball tip drumstick pastrami ribeye. Andouille tail bacon ball tip brisket
        </div>
    </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Here a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hbmsxy7a/

Answer (score 0):

You have competing `onchange` properties defined for both "yes" and "no." When you click one, they both change, so both functions fire: `showOptions()` and `hideOptions()`. The end result is your div stays hidden.

I suggest using `onClick` instead of `onChange`. Also, if your page is using HTML4, integers are not allowed as IDs, so you may be able to fix the issue by adding a prefix to your IDs:

```
echo "<div id=\"prefix" . $option_id . "\" ...";
```

And your JS function becomes:

```
function showOptions(id)
{
    document.getElementById("prefix" + id).style.display="block"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the way it gets hidden based on all the answers above.

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<li>".$row['question'];

if($row['question_form_type']=='boolean')
   {
       $option_id = $type_array[$x];
      $option_id .=$row['question_id']+100000;
      echo "<br><select onChange = 'showOptions(value)' required>><Option value = 'yes_$option_id' >Yes</option> ";



      echo "<option value = $option_id>No</option></select>
      <div id ='$option_id' style = 'border-color: #ccc; border-style: solid; margin: 2px; display:none'>";
      $optionSQL = "select option_id, option_suggestion from sandbox_feedback_options where question_id = ".$row['question_id']." and option_type like  '%".$type_array[$x]."%'";
      $oresult = $conn->query($optionSQL);
         if ($oresult->num_rows > 0) {
      while($orow = $oresult->fetch_assoc()) {
             $od = $orow['option_id']+10000;
          echo "<input type = 'checkbox' name = $od>".$orow['option_suggestion']."</input><p>";

       }
 echo "</div>";}


    }
echo "</li>";
}}
echo "</ol></div>";

}
```